# Can not execute jupyter notebook using powershell. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook

I installed python 3.8.1(32) at default directory, also installed jupyter notebook through Windows PowerShell.

Every time i launched jupyter notebook through PowerShell, [I get this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tut3U.png) not executing notebook.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in jupyter notebook with python 3.8.x. [This is the current workaround](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/5047).